# Outlook Email Message Access Failure after new Third Party Popup

Tags: google-chrome, outlook.com, firefox

Since yesterday, after I log in to Outlook online, a popup appears. It starts:

"We and various third parties process data to: store and/or access information..."

(The text is like an image and cannot be copied.) There are two options to continue:

**Advanced Settings** and (highlighted) **Okay and continue to site**

With either option, I cannot then access the content of any emails. I see only the titles (and some of the body text) of the emails in my "Focused" inbox. Clicking on another inbox such as "Other" reveals the message:

"Your request can't be completed right now. Retry (button)"

Clicking on the title of an email in the "Focused" inbox displays another message:

"Your message can't be displayed right now Please check your network connection and try again later"

I tried disabling all my advertising cookie restrictions temporarily, but that didn't fix it. There may be something else wrong as clicking "Save" on Outlook Settings, and then exiting, produced a pop-up asking if I wanted to save.

When I access the site using Firefox, on the same machine, there is no problem. On my other machine, it's exactly the opposite: no problem with Chrome, but *Firefox* then has the problem described above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was I went into settings and I stumbled on the forwarding part when it asked me to verify my Microsoft account. I had to login in again, but that seems to solve the problem. It most likely had nothing to do with forwarding at all, except that it led me to re-login, which ultimately was the key to the problem.